# F# can't use datagrid in WPF of .net in interactive way

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

My script is below:

```
#light

#r "WindowsBase"    
#r "PresentationCore"    
#r "PresentationFramework"

open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls

let window = new System.Windows.Window(Name="Test",Width=500.0,Height=500.0)    
window.Visibility <- Visibility.Visible    
window.Show()    
let mutable wp = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid()
```

Initialize window is OK, but when i initialize a datagrid , there is a error:

graph.fsx(18,46): error FS0039: The type 'DataGrid' is not defined.

but when i put the mouse cursor over "System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid()", there
is a pop-up window showing the definition of datagrid.

So what did i miss? How to use datagrid in F#.

Answer (score 1):

When you reference the PresentationFramework assembly without specifying a version fsi will load the 3.0 version, which does not include the DataGrid. To reference the 4.0 version you can either use the fully qualified name:

```
#r "PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
```

or you could use the full path to the assembly. On my system this is:

```
#r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\PresentationFramework.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(VS.95).aspx):

> Namespace:  System.Windows.Controls
>
> Assembly:
> System.Windows.Controls.Data (in
> System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll)

You need to reference the correct assembly:

```
#r "System.Windows.Controls.Data"
```

Comment: sorry, i mean i want to use datagrid in .net 4 instead that in silverlight, but anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cause of this in F# 2.0, but the issue seems to be resolved in F# 3.0